# Python Multiprocessing Pool.map

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pool

I try to read files with multiprocessing in python. Here is a small example:

```
import multiprocessing
from time import *

class class1():
    def function(self, datasheetname):
        #here i start reading my datasheet

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Test with multiprosessing
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
    pool.map(class1("Datasheetname"))
    pool.close()
```

Now I get the following error:

> TypeError: map() missing 1 required positional argument: 'iterable'

In another thread in this board I got the hint to do this with ThreadPool, but I don't know how to do that. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you need to do this in parallel, or do you need to read in a bunch of CSV/Excel sheets? If the latter, maybe look into using [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) or [pandas.read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html), which can read in multiple files/sheets with a single call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map):

> **map(func, iterable[, chunksize])**
>
> A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (it supports only  one iterable argument though). It blocks until the result is ready.
>
> This method chops the iterable into a number of chunks which it submits to the process pool as separate tasks. The (approximate) size of these chunks can be specified by setting chunksize to a positive integer.

You need to pass an iterable of which each element is passed to the target `func` as an argument in each process.

Example:

```
def function(sheet):
    # do something with sheet
    return "foo"

pool = Pool(processes=4)
result = pool.map(function, ['sheet1', 'sheet2', 'sheet3', 'sheet4'])
# result will be ['foo', 'foo', 'foo', 'foo']
```